# Duplicating and Renaming a file and storing name in Database

Tags: coldfusion

I have a register page that asks for information like `employee_number, user_name, user_pass, firstname, lastname, position, email, phone_extension, department, picture`. Once they fill this information out and they hit register it all gets uploaded into a database.

Is it possible to have it create a profile page specific to that user based on the information in the database?

For example, if I registered to have it create `DavidBriertonProfile.cfm` from my template `Profile.cfm` and have it add `DavidBriertonProfile.cfm` in the database so I can use that name to reference later. But is it possible to take my template `Profile.cfm` and rename it based on there name and have it added to `profiles/(TherenameProfile).cfm`

I have been playing with cffile in order to create a path but I need it to be behind the scenes selecting my template file where the user never sees any of this.

```
<cffile 
     action       = "upload" 
     file         = "#expandPath("/webapps/dash/profiles/profile.cfm")#"
     destination  = "#expandPath("/webapps/dash/profiles/")#" 
     nameConflict = "MakeUnique" 
     result       = "myfile" 
   />
```

Comment: A better idea would be to create one page, userProfile.cfm, that accepts a form or url variable that specifies the user.

Comment: This is very elementary stuff.  Do you know how to create and process url variables?

Comment: Thank you for the post sorry my lack of knowledge but thank you for leading me into the right direction!

Comment: (Edit) This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  BTW, you might want to review some tutorials on dynamic CF applications to get a better understanding of how to effectively construct a database driven application.

Comment: cffile tag does not allow `file` attribute for `action="upload"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two primary options

Create a static file from a coldfusion template...

```
<cfsavecontent variable="filecontent">
    <cfinclude template="profile.cfm" />
</cfsavecontent>
<cffile action="write" file="profiles/#FirstNameLastName#Profile.html" output="#filecontent#" />
<!--- it looks like the "nameconflict" option is only available for upload action so will have to deal with that --->
```

Create a file just for setting the userid and including profile.cfm

```
<cffile action="write"
    file="profiles/#FirstNameLastName#.cfm"
    output="<cfset userid ='#UserID' /><cfinclude template='../profile.cfm' />"
/>
```

Some other options include

- Save the name of the unique cfm file you would create (ex: DavidSmith12Profile) but don't actually create it and instead use the OnMissingTemplate function in Application.cfc to take the name supplied and perform a database lookup and then show the profile result
- Peform a URL rewrite on the webserver to transform any request to paths of format /profiles/(.+) to /profile.cfm?filename={\1} and then do a database lookup by the filename directly in profile.cfm

enjoy

Comment: IMO the solution really depends on the objective (which unfortunately was not very clear from the question).  IF the goal is SEO friendly url's, then rewriting is definitely the way to go. (No need to generate a physical file for *every* single profile.) However, if the goal is just to display profile information from a database, then all you need is a single profile.cfm script which accepts some sort of member id parameter.